# Are here any Firebug (Firefox) plugins that will display CSS property values when editing

Tags: firebug

I was wondering if there is any such plugin for Firebug (Firefox) that will display a list or dropdown menu of possible values for a property when your editing the css property.

for Example:

If I want to edit the `display` property, when I click on the value, a tooltip or menu will be available with `inline` `inline-block` `...`.

Seems like a stretch but I thought maybe someone came up with this.
Or if not with firebug, are there any other firefox developer tools that may have this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not a new plugin. The functionality is there inside firebug. Just click on the property value and move up and down with the arrows on your keyboard to explore all available option.